# How to use LIKE clause/condition in Arcpy.Exists/Delete

Tags: arcpy, sql-server

I would like to delete several raster files in an ArcSDE SQL Server database.  I would like to do so with Arcpy.  How can I succesfully use a LIKE condition to delete all files in my database that have a certain string of characters, such as `_`.  Meaning that I want to delete all files that contain an underscore.  Using the example from Esri, where would I delete all files that for instance contain `roadbuffer`.

```
import arcpy

# Set the current workspace
#
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/base/data.gdb"

# Check for existence of data before deleting
#
if arcpy.Exists("roadbuffer"):
    arcpy.Delete_management("roadbuffer")
```

Comment: `DROP TABLE` doesn't have a wild-card either.  It's simple enough to list all tables and drop those that meet some criteria.  Personally, I only use cleanup scripts on databases of which I'm not particularly fond (even if I have a validated backup)

Comment: If python is not your strong point consider using model builder with an iterator. You could knock that together in a minute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wildcard searching is built into [`arcpy.ListRasters()`](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//018v0000003w000000):

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/base/data.gdb"

for raster in arcpy.ListRasters("*_*"):
    arcpy.Delete_management(raster)
```

If you want more advanced wildcarding/filtering, you'll need to use [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).